# SQL: Create a view that creates a position based on a date

Tags: sql, view

I'm actually running oracle, but when I copied my example into sqlfiddle, it wouldnt run if I chose oracle instead of mysql, perhaps the fiddle version of oracle is different from mine.
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44933/1

```
CREATE TABLE Positiontest(
ID VARCHAR(20),
code CHAR(06),
registrationdate DATE,
PRIMARY KEY(ID,code)
);

INSERT INTO Positiontest VALUES('01','COM002','2012-12-11');
INSERT INTO Positiontest VALUES('02','COM002','2012-12-12');
INSERT INTO Positiontest VALUES('01','COM003','2012-12-11');
```

This gives me positiontest table:

```
  ID     CODE      REGISTRATIONDATE
  01     COM002    2012-12-11
  02     COM002    2012-12-12
  01     COM003    2012-12-11
```

**I want to create a view that looks like:**

```
  ID     CODE      POSITION
  01     COM002    1
  02     COM002    2
  01     COM003    1
```

The order is not important, aslong as there
is one uniqe position for each code.

Comment: It doesn't work on SQLFiddle because you are relying on implicit data type conversion `'2012-12-11'` is not a date, but a character literal which gets converted based on the locale settings. If you use a date literal or the to_date() function it will work, e.g: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6d3f9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `row_number()` function:

```
select pt.*,
       row_number() over (partition by code order by code) as Position
from PositionTest pt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID, code, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY CODE)
FROM Positiontest
```